# Best practice to check contains key and check for null/empty in JSON?

Tags: java, playframework, jackson, playframework-2.2, jsonnode

I will receive the following JSON request to my service.

```
{
  "city" : "Hyderabad",
  "state" : "Telangana",
  "country" : "India"
}
```

Sometimes In the request, I might not get the city field or city field might be empty which is not expected. So, I'm handling that in the following way:


 **payload** is my request JSON.

```
if ( payload.has("city") && !payload.get("city").equals("") )
```

I'm handling it in the above way. But the problem is that If I add new mandatory again then I need to add two more conditions as:

```
if ( payload.has("city") && !payload.get("city").equals("") && payload.has("newKey") && !payload.get("newKey").equals("") )
```

1. check whether the key is available or not.
2. check whether the value is not empty.

   **Is there any best practice to solve this?**

Comment: you have to use `request().body().asJson()` for sure, but you mentioned the methods of request().body().asFormUrlEncoded()

Comment: do share your controller code

Comment: @Rajat Yes. I'm using JsonNode payload = request().body().asJson(); to get the request object.

Answer (score 0):

I would deserialize the JSON payload into an object, then you can use the combination of getters as you like.

```
MyObj toValue = mapper.readValue(parser, MyObj.class);
```

If you want to stick to your original approach I would then create some helper methods to make it all more readable:

```
private boolean hasCity(String payload) {
   return payload.has("city") && !payload.get("city").equals("");
}
```

Comment: Whatever you said was true. But I found this now. https://json-schema.org/implementations.html this will help for any kind of validations in the JSON. It has great support as well. Check that once.